# updated method on ListMap

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm using ListMap because I need to keep the insertion order in place. After initializing it seems it works. but when I call updated on it the order gets messed up. 1- Why is that? 2- Is there any other `MapLike` that doesn't have this problem, if not how should I update the map without problem?

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

scala> val a = ListMap(0 -> "A", 1 -> "B", 2 ->"C")
a: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String] = Map(0 -> A, 1 -> B, 2 -> C)

scala> a.foreach(println)
(0,A)
(1,B)
(2,C)

scala> val b = a.updated(1, "D")
b: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String] = Map(0 -> A, 2 -> C, 1 -> D)
scala> b.foreach(println)
(0,A)
(2,C)
(1,D)
```

Answer (score 3):

I could not find any existent immutable collection with desired property. But it could be crafted manually.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{IntMap, Map, MapLike} 

class OrderedMap[K, +V] private[OrderedMap](backing: Map[K, V], val order: IntMap[K], coorder: Map[K, Int], extSize: Int)
  extends Map[K, V] with MapLike[K, V, OrderedMap[K, V]] {
  def +[B1 >: V](kv: (K, B1)): OrderedMap[K, B1] = {
    val (k, v) = kv
    if (backing contains k)
      new OrderedMap(backing + kv, order, coorder, extSize)
    else new OrderedMap(backing + kv, order + (extSize -> k), coorder + (k -> extSize), extSize + 1)
  }
  def get(key: K): Option[V] = backing.get(key)

  def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = for (key <- order.valuesIterator) yield (key, backing(key))

  def -(key: K): OrderedMap[K, V] = if (backing contains key) {
    val index = coorder(key)
    new OrderedMap(backing - key, order - index, coorder - key, extSize)
  } else this

  override def empty: OrderedMap[K, V] = OrderedMap.empty[K, V]
}

object OrderedMap {
  def empty[K, V] = new OrderedMap[K, V](Map.empty, IntMap.empty, Map.empty, 0)

  def apply[K, V](assocs: (K, V)*): OrderedMap[K, V] = assocs.foldLeft(empty[K, V])(_ + _)
}
```

Here `order` is preserved insertion order map (probably with "holes"). `coorder` special field needed for efficient handling element removal. `extSize` is basically `order.lastkey + 1` but more straightforward

Now you can verify that

```
val a = OrderedMap(0 -> "A", 1 -> "B", 2 -> "C")
a.foreach(println)  
val b = a.updated(1, "D")
b.foreach(println)
```

prints

```
(0,A)
(1,B)
(2,C)
```

and

```
(0,A)
(1,D)
(2,C)
```

Comment: wow, thanks for answer, looks promising but for some serializing reason I cannot use this very easily , but thanks

Comment: @Omid what troubles do you have with serialization?

Comment: I have to define a custom serializer for this and it's a pain

Comment: You could just redefine as `case class` and drop `private` at constructor if needed

Answer (score 1):

From the scala doc for `updated`

> "This method allows one to create a new map with an additional mapping
>   from key to value."

Note it does not say "with a different value of an existing key". So when you updated with `1->D`, that's a new/additional mapping. So it appears at the end of the list, preserving insertion order. The old mapping `1->C` is no longer present in the map.

So it's not "messed up" and it's not a problem. It's doing what it's documented to do, the mappings are in insertion order.

Comment: actually if you read the whole thing: 
>  If the map contains already a mapping for key, it will be overridden by this function
and because the only reason of existence LisMap is Oredr, then any user expect ordering

Comment: Yes. And the mapping for key has been overridden. By the new one. It doesn't say the value of the previous entry will be overridden. I think either behaviour can be argued for and against but I would argue that  for Listmap, `(listMap updated (x, y)).last == (x, y)` is also something that should be true for all x (and y).

Comment: I've run into this as well. We would welcome a pull request that improved the documentation on this.

Comment: @SethTisue, you're stalking me :) I'll attempt to work on this, if time allows. BTW, I can make neither head nor tail of what the mutable ListMap does with update and ordering...